# Estimation for covariance in the context of mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, covariance

There are 4 subjects and 4 measured data of each subject and the data should be interpreted in the context of a mixed model. What is a reasonable estimation for the covariance of y?

```
y <- data.frame(response = c(10,19,27,28,9,13,25,29,4,10,20,18,5,6,12,17),
                treatment = factor(rep(1:4, 4)),
                subject = factor(rep(1:4, each = 4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following scripts:

```
library(nlme)
g=groupedData(response~treatment | subject,data=y)
a=lme(response~treatment,data=g,random=~1 |subject,correlation=corAR1())
a
```